# Select rows where column value starts with a string AND ends with an even number

Tags: sql, oracle, select

This is in an Oracle DB:

I need to return the values from a column that start with a specific string AND end with an even (then odd) number.
For example:

```
ABC001
DEF001
ABD001
ABD002
OPQ001
ABD003
ABD004
```

I need a query that returns ONLY ABD002 and ABD004.

The last 3 characters of the string are always numeric, if that helps.

Comment: Please show what you tried

Comment: I'm with user8834780 here. You haven't even shown an issue you are dealing with. You are supposed to show us what you tried and where you are stuck. Please do so next time. Don't let us do your work. I've posted an answer here, though, because such task is usually dealt with with regular expressions and nobody mentioned them. On the other hand: such a problem usually stems from a bad database design. Why do you have one column only when you are obviously interested in the two separate parts? Looks like this should be two columns instead.

Comment: fair enough.  I'll keep that in mind next time.   I had an ugly looking "select * from mytable where uniqueid like 'ABD%' and ( like '%0' or like '%2' )" etc ... I just knew there was a far better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `substr` to extract the last three characters, `to_number` to treat them as a number, and then `mod` it by 2 to see if it's even:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable 
WHERE  mycolumn LIKE 'ABD%' AND MOD(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(mycolumn, -3)), 2) = 0
```

Comment: I like that.  I'll give it a go, but this might be the easiest way to go about it. :)

Answer (score 1):

slight variation:

```
WITH DATA(VAL) AS(
SELECT 'ABC001' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEF001' from dual union all
SELECT 'ABD001' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABD002' from dual union all
SELECT 'OPQ001' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABD003' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABD004' from dual 
)
select val  from data
WHERE MOD(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(VAL,-3)),2)=0
and SUBSTR(VAL,1,length(VAL)-3) = 'ABD'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a regular expression:

```
select * 
from mytable
where regexp_like(mycolumn, 'ABD..[02468]');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `LIKE` operator:

```
WHERE str LIKE 'ABD%' AND (
    str LIKE '%0' OR
    str LIKE '%2' OR
    str LIKE '%4' OR
    str LIKE '%6' OR
    str LIKE '%8'
)
```

PS: an even number ends with 0, 2, 4, 6 or 8 regardless of the number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
select column from table where substr(column,1,3) = 'ABD' and mod(to_number(substr(column,4,3)),2)=0;
```

That ought to do it, I think.

If you have a significantly large table, and need to index, you may have to get creative with function based indexes.

Perhaps:

```
create index column_fbi on table(substr(column,1,3),mod(to_number(substr(column,4,3)),2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try [***this***](http://rextester.com/FWPG93077) :

```
with tab(str) as
(
  select 'ABC001' from dual union all
  select 'DEF001' from dual union all
  select 'ABD001' from dual union all
  select 'ABD002' from dual union all
  select 'OPQ001' from dual union all
  select 'ABD003' from dual union all
  select 'ABD004' from dual 
)
select str
  from tab
 where mod(substr(str,length(str),1),2) = 0
   and str like 'ABD%';
```

P.S. There's no need to make a conversion a string , which is completely composed of integers, to number, Oracle implicitly assumes as a number for a collation as in the above `mod` operation.